# Getting Key error with countryinfo package

Tags: python, dictionary, package, keyerror, country

I have a list of countries in a file and when I try to search for the CountryInfo('Africa').region() using the package countryinfo for Africa, the region of which is Africa again - it throws an error.

- Any idea on how to fix this? Are there any workarounds with the use of same package?
- Also, is there a repository from which I can check what are the allowed names for countries?

For example, it works with country name as - South Africa but not Africa.

```
Error: _region = self.__countries[self.__country_name]['region']
KeyError: 'africa'
```

Comment: Please provide enough code to make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In what world is `'Africa'` a country? Try creating `ci = CountryInfo()` and look at `ci.all().keys()` - those are all the country names it supports. Unless `_region` and `__countries` are things you're defining yourself on a new class, you shouldn't be accessing them. There's no guarantee they'll continue to work and there's other ways to get at the data.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the African countries like this(code below). You can further select the required country from the new dictionary `african_countries`

**Note**: In CountryInfo, 'Africa' is a region and not a country.

```
from countryinfo import CountryInfo
country = CountryInfo()
african_countries = {k:v for k,v in country.all().items() if 'region' in v.keys() and v['region'] == 'Africa'}
print(african_countries.keys())
```

**Output of keys:**

```
dict_keys(['algeria', 'angola', 'benin', 'botswana', 'british indian ocean territory', 'burkina faso', 'burundi', 'cameroon', 'cape verde', 'central african republic', 'chad', 'comoros', ...  'zimbabwe'])
```

Further details of the country is in the values of the dictionary.